# converting csv files to a dictionary of lists in python

Tags: python

I have a CSV file that looks this row by row

1. lion, gazelle
2. jackle, grass, zebra, gazelle
3. gazelle, grass
4. zebra, grass

and I want to take this and convert it into a dictionary where each row is its own list with the key being the first element of the row. the output should look something like this

```
d=open("example.csv")
data={}
l=[]
for line in d.read():
    l.append(line)
for line in l:
    key=line[0]
    data[key]=line[1:]
print(data)
```

the output should look like this

```
gazelle: grass
jackal: grass, zebra, gazelle
lion: gazelle
zebra: grass
```

Comment: You have to split each line by commas to a list of item strings.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
import csv
reader = csv.reader(open('example.csv', 'r'))
d = {}
for row in reader:
    d[row[0]] = row[1::]
print(d)
```

input:

```
lion,gazelle
jackle,grass,zebra,gazelle
gazelle,grass
zebra,grass
```

output:

```
{
    'lion': ['gazelle'], 
    'zebra': ['grass'], 
    'jackle': ['grass', 'zebra', 'gazelle'], 
    'gazelle': ['grass']
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`csv.reader()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) from built-in [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module to read the file and then loop through the rows. Create an entry on the `dict` with the first element on each row as a `key` and the rest of the row as `value` list. Note the inline ternary operator (`stmt if condition else stmt`) just to avoid an `exception` when there is only one element on the row.

**Input:**

```
lion,gazelle
jackle,grass,zebra,gazelle
gazelle,grass
zebra,grass
```

And you can use this snippet:

```
import csv

outputDict = {}
with open("file.csv", newline="") as csvfile:
    data = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=",")
    for row in data:
        outputDict[row[0]] = row[1:] if len(row) > 1 else []

print(outputDict)
```

**Outputs:**

```
{
  'lion': ['gazelle'], 
  'jackle': ['grass', 'zebra', 'gazelle'], 
  'gazelle': ['grass'], 
  'zebra': ['grass']
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's another way to do the same thing without the csv module:

```
with open("example.csv", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    my_dict = {}
    for line in lines:
        words = line.strip("\n").split(", ")
        my_dict[words[0]] = words[1:]
```

Comment: It will work only for a subset of CSVs, namely those not containing new lines in cells. For example, [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values#Example) won't be parsed correctly.